# jQuery Geocomplete Plugin Autocomplete Landmark

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, geocomplete

Try "San Jose Convention Center" over here - http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/map.html

It won't work.

Try the same here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

It will work.

Anyone know how to get something like this working with the jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the types-option to `['geocode','establishment']`

The default for the geocomplete-plugin is `['geocode']`, so it will return only results with the type `geocode`.

The places-autocomplete-example uses no types-parameter per default, so it will not filter the results by type.

Comment: also remember to change 'type' to 'types'. This had me stuck for awhile.

Comment: if you add `types: ['geocode', '(regions)']` it doesn't work.